# Strange CSS Div - Help Needed

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some help on how to realize something like this:

[img http://img1.firenex.net/ssFan8c00f9Ul1QnQzGt.png](http://img1.firenex.net/ssFan8c00f9Ul1QnQzGt.png)

The difficulty is that the ribbon image is the header of this DIV, while I want the height of the whole wrapper be automatic, based on how much text I write inside of it.

I can't find a way out from this. Any help?

This is the code I have to now.

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="sidebarElementWrapper"><div class="sidebarElement"></div></div>
</div>
```

The CSS (consider this is a sidebar):

```
#sidebar {
width: 225px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
min-height: 100px;
float: left;
}

.sidebarElement {
width: 244px;
min-height: 100px;
margin-top: 10px;
background: url(img/ribbon.png) no-repeat top center;
}

.sidebarElementWrapper {
width: 244px;
height: auto;
min-height: 20px;
background: url(img/SidebarElementWrapper.png) repeat-y;
}
```

It works but when I type some text inside of it and set some padding, it just breaks out..

Comment: Posting the code would help a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using absolute positioning makes things easier, i think.

JS FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/qf49w/59/

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="ribbon"></div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget tellus at elit sagittis ultrices non nec sem. Curabitur sit amet nibh elit, vitae rhoncus velit. Sed ac nisl ut felis pretium fermentum. Donec sodales lorem ut nibh dapibus id tempus dui tincidunt.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #sidebar { 
        width: 160px; 
        height: auto;  
        background: white; 
        position:relative; 
        padding:40px 10px 10px 10px; 
        margin:40px auto; 
    }  

    #ribbon {
        position:absolute;
        top: -25px;;
        left:-60px;  
        height:60px;
        width:290px;
        background:url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/e/R/Z/Y/n/red-white-ribbon-md.png) no-repeat 0 0;  
    }
```

I simplified your structure, you will only need a sidebar container for the content and a ribbon div which will contain the image.

I use absolute positioning to position the ribbon in relation to the sidebar ( position:relative ) then setting the sidebar top padding to about the same height as the ribbon container, making the text start only below the ribbon.

Comment: removed z-index and overflow:visible, no need.

Answer (score 1):

There's not quite enough information for me to go off, but what about something similar to this:

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="sidebarElementWrapper"><div class="sidebarHeader">Header</div><div class="sidebarBody">Content</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
width: 225px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
min-height: 100px;
float: left;
}

.sidebarHeader {
width: 244px;
height: 45px;
margin-top: 10px;
background: url(img/ribbon.png) no-repeat top center;
}

.sidebarBody {
width: 225px;
margin-left: 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebarElementWrapper {
width: 244px;
height: auto;
min-height: 20px;
}
```

A few things to note:
1.  This is assuming that 'ribbon.png' is 244 x 45 px.
2.  I've added another div with class `sidebarBody` and renamed `sidebarElement` to `sidebarHeader`

This solution will still need a little work, but will hopefully give you enough insight as to address your problem.